# How to display sections within a select dropdown using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

There is a select dropdown that currently displays a list of values (All Car Makes).
The new requirement is to have sections within the same select dropdown, so that it shows a new set of values (Common Car Makes) under a section and along with the existing (All Car Makes).

How can this be achieved using AngularJS?

Existing code :

```
<select ng-model="vm.vehicleSelection.selected.make" 
  ng-options="m for m in vm.vehicleSelection.makes">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add anything you have tried?

Comment: Thanks @mast3rd3mon, The below code worked :)

Comment: Hi @georgeawg ,  this is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343484/how-to-add-a-header-in-dropdown-list-with-ng-options-demo/ , But with a better heading I guess. I have posted my answer there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked :)

If we have a list for each section of values, we can display it as :

```
<select 
ng-model="vm.vehicleSelection.selected.make" >
 <option value="">Please select</option>
 <optgroup label="Common Car Makes">
  <option ng-repeat="commonMake in vm.vehicleSelection.commonMakes" ng-value="commonMake">{{commonMake}}</option>
 </optgroup>

 <optgroup label="All Car Makes">
  <option ng-repeat="make in vm.vehicleSelection.makes" ng-value="make">{{make}} 
  </option>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```